# Cannot connect to Samba folders via wired internet, works over WIFI

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, unix, samba

I am trying to access a Samba shared folder from several computers on the same network using windows 10. I am able to, when connected to the wifi, access said folders on my laptop. When i try to access these same folders with the same login information using a PC using an Ethernet connection, i get the error:

```
"Folder is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network 
resource. 

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same 
user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all 
previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again"
```

The smb.conf file is:

```
 #
 # Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
 #
 #
 # This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
 # smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
 # here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which
 # are not shown in this example
 #
 # Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
 # commented-out examples in this file.
 #  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
 #    differs from the default Samba behaviour
 #  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
 #    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
 #    enough to be mentioned here
 #
 # NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
 # "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic
 # errors.

 #======================= Global Settings =======================

 [global]

     netbios name = ubuntu
     security = user


 ## Browsing/Identification ###

 # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
    workgroup = WORKGROUP

 # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
         server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

 # Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
 # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
 #   wins support = no

 # WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
 # Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
 ;   wins server = w.x.y.z

 # This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
    dns proxy = no

 #### Networking ####

 # The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
 # This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
 # interface names are normally preferred
 ;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

 # Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
 # 'interfaces' option above to use this.
 # It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
 # not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
 # option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
 ;   bind interfaces only = yes



 #### Debugging/Accounting ####

 # This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
 # that connects
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

 # Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
    max log size = 1000

 # If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
 # parameter to 'yes'.
 #   syslog only = no

 # We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
 # should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
 # through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
    syslog = 0

 # Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


 ####### Authentication #######

 # Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
 # values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
 # domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
 # directory domain controller".
 #
 # Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
 # Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
 # running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
 # new domain.
    server role = standalone server

 # If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
 # password database type you are using.
    passdb backend = tdbsam

    obey pam restrictions = yes

 # This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
 # password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
 # passdb is changed.
    unix password sync = yes

 # For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
 # parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
 # sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

 # This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
 # when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
 # 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
    pam password change = yes

 # This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
 # to anonymous connections
    map to guest = bad user

 ########## Domains ###########

 #
 # The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
 # classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
 # or 'domain logons' is set
 #

 # It specifies the location of the user's
 # profile directory from the client point of view) The following
 # required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
 # below)
 ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
 # Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
 # (this is Samba's default)
 #   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

 # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
 # It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
 # point of view)
 ;   logon drive = H:
 #   logon home = \\%N\%U

 # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
 # It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
 # in the [netlogon] share
 # NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
 ;   logon script = logon.cmd

 # This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
 # RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
 # password; please adapt to your needs
 ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

 # This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the
 # SAMR RPC pipe.
 # The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
 ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
 # This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
 # RPC pipe.
 ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

 ############ Misc ############

 # Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
 # on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
 # of the machine that is connecting
 ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

 # Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
 # for something else.)
 ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
 ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
 ;   template shell = /bin/bash

 # Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
 # with the net usershare command.

 # Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
 ;   usershare max shares = 100

 # Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
 # public shares, not just authenticated ones
    usershare allow guests = yes

 #======================= Share Definitions =======================

 # Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
 # to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
 # user's home directory as \\server\username
 ;[homes]
 ;   comment = Home Directories
 ;   browseable = no

 # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
 # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
 ;   read only = yes

 # File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
 # create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
 ;   create mask = 0700

 # Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
 # create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
 ;   directory mask = 0700
 # By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
 # with access to the samba server.
 # Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
 # can connect to \\server\username
 # This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
 ;   valid users = %S

 # Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
 # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
 ;[netlogon]
 ;   comment = Network Logon Service
 ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
 ;   guest ok = yes
 ;   read only = yes

 # Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
 # users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
 # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
 # The path below should be writable by all users so that their
 # profile directory may be created the first time they log on
 ;[profiles]
 ;   comment = Users profiles
 ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
 ;   guest ok = no
 ;   browseable = no
 ;   create mask = 0600
 ;   directory mask = 0700

 [printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = yes
    create mask = 0700

 # Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
 # printer drivers
 [print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable = yes
    read only = yes
    guest ok = no
 # Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
 # You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
 # admin users are members of.
 # Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
 # to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
 ;   write list = root, @lpadmin


 [wahlshare]
         comment = Samba on Ubuntu
         path = /home/wahl_d/wahlshare
         read only = no
         browsable = yes

 #Mask settings and guest are tests, change later
 [brooklynshare]
         comment = Brooklyn's Samba Share
         path = /home/welsh_bd/brooklynshare
         read only = no
         browsable = yes
         create mask = 777
         directory mask = 2775

 [briggsshare]
         comment = Briggs' Samba Folder
         path = /var/www/html/briggs
         valid users = briggs
         public = no
         read only = no
         browsable = yes
```

What we've tried for samba fix so far:
* PC: tell it to allow network discovery. That was already done
* sudo ufw disable. No effect. (It's re-enabled now.)
* Allowing guest access in conf file. Works, but insecure.
* using chmod777 to change permissions. No effect.

Comment: The error message says you are already connected to the server once, so second one is refused. Are you enabling WiFi *and* Ethernet?

Comment: We tried to disable WiFi, it seems to have made the problem worse. Before, I would get through one sign in screen, only to be denied by another once i tried to access the specific file. After disabling WiFi, I am getting an error message before any sign in and the error message is the same on both PC and laptop. The error message is as follows: "Windows cannot access IP address.  check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network."    @harrymc